# how to convert this query to linq with left outer join

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I am getting different record set while converting this query to linq. can any one help me.

```
select p.Id  , p.lastname    from Participants p
left outer  join  CertificationStatusLevels c on p.CertificationStatusID = c.ID
left outer           join   BUOrgs po on p.PrimaryOrgID = po.ID
inner   join participantRoles pr on  p.id= pr.ParticipantId
inner join roles Ro on pr.RolesId=Ro.id
where p.IsActive =1   and ro.id=4 and  pr.IsActive =1
```

query

```
from p in _unitOfWork.Context.Participants
join c in _unitOfWork.Context.CertificationStatusLevels on 
p.CertificationStatusID equals c.ID into pc
join po in _unitOfWork.Context.BUOrgs on p.PrimaryOrgID equals po.ID into bp
join pr in _unitOfWork.Context.ParticipantRoles on p.Id equals
pr.ParticipantId
join ro in _unitOfWork.Context.Roles on pr.RolesId equals ro.Id
from Combined1 in pc.DefaultIfEmpty()
from Combined2 in bp.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Comment: Please also include your erroneous attempt

Comment: The LINQ query is incomplete. Also it's unclear why you need those left outer joins (in both queries) since I don't see any usage of the `c` and `po`.